# Conditional Probability Example

Tags: conditional-probability

I don't understand the following example,

> Consider two urns, the first containing two white and seven black balls, and
>   the second containing five white and six black balls. We 
>   flip a fair coin and then draw a
>   ball from the first urn or the second urn depending upon whether the outcome was heads or
>   tails. What is the conditional probability that the outcome of the toss was heads given that
>   a white ball was selected?

What is the relationship between coin and selecting a ball ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found using [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Say that $A$ is the even that the outcome of the toss was heads, and $B$ is the even that the white ball was selected.

$P(B | A) = \frac{2}{9}$, because that means the first urn was used.

$P(A) = 0.5$, because the coin is fair.

$P(B) = 0.5 \frac{2}{9} + 0.5 \frac{5}{11}$, by the [Law Of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Using Bayes' law, you can get $P(A|B)$ from this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you drew a white ball. Both first Urn (A), and the second Urn (B), have a white balls in them (2 and 5 resp.). The choice whether we will draw a ball from Urn A or Urn B depends on whether the coin showed heads or tails.

The question asks you to tell the probability of coin showing a head if a white ball had been drawn. Alternatively, it asks you to tell the probability of the ball being from Urn A (since we chose A if we get head), if it is a white ball.

Let us define W to be the event of ball being white. A of ball being from urn A, and B of ball being from Urn B.

*P(A|W)* (Our answer) = *P(A.W)/P(W)*

Now, *P(A.W) = 2/9, P(B.W) = 5/11, P(W) = 1/2*P(A.W) + 1/2*P(A.B)*

Plug the value. Get the answer. As to your question, **the relationship between tossing a coin and selecting a ball is that outcome of the coin decides which urn we are going to draw from, and thus changes the probability distribution of drawing the ball, or chances of getting a white(or a black ball).**